# Android.os.Process.killProcess not working

Tags: android, process

Hi I am making an android app that closes the google music app based on a timer.I am using the following code for shutting down the background `music` process:

```
ActivityManager a = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
int pid = android.os.Process.getUidForName("com.google.android.music");
a.killBackgroundProcesses("com.google.android.music");
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

Even after using both methods of `killProcess` and `killBackgroundProcesses`, it is not working on my device.Any guesses why it is so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?  I am wondering the same.

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"
android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"
```

and

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

> Whether or not the task initiated by this activity should be excluded
>   from the list of recently used applications ("recent apps"). That is,
>   when this activity is the root activity of a new task, this attribute
>   determines whether the task should not appear in the list of recent
>   apps. "true" if the task should be excluded from the list; "false" if
>   it should be included. The default value is "false".

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exclude

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Tried it but still it does not close the app. In fact, if I try to close the running activity instead of another process, even then by putting my package name, it does not close it.                                                                  By Debugging the application I also found out that the pid value that I get by the above method for my running process and the one I get by using : "android.os.Process.myPid()" are different.The former shows 24587 while the latter shows -1. -1 is shown for both the music process and the application process.